# Elementos option se repiten dentro de un select nodejs ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, nodejs, express, asincronismo

Tengo 2 selects uno que tiene ciertas marcas de autos, cuando el usuario hace clic en alguna marca, se hace la consulta asíncrona al modelo y trae todos los autos de esa marca.

con esa información yo completo el select correspondiente a los modelos de esa marca.

Ahora si el usuario ademas de seleccionar la marca selecciona el modelo hace otra consulta asíncrona y trae los autos correspondientes a esa marca y al modelo que se le hizo clic.

Hasta ahí todo funciona bien.

El primer problema es que me trae modelos repetidos, en el model de mongo yo tengo dos autos del mismo modelo suburban 2020

Quiero solo mostrar uno de ellos, he intentado con new Set pero lo que obtengo es:

["Suburban 2020"]
script.js:202 (2) ["Suburban 2020", "Corvette 2018"]
script.js:202 (2) ["Suburban 2020", "Corvette 2018"]
script.js:202 (3) ["Suburban 2020", "Corvette 2018", "Malibu 2019"]

Osea cuando hago el push al array vacio me crea un array para cada uno de los elementos que se van enviando. el ultimo sin elementos repetidos, entonces no sabría como hacer para crearle selects solo al ultimo.

Ahora logro crear un option para cada uno de los modelos (incluyendo los repetidos) pero cuando selecciono uno lo duplica tal como muestra la imagen.

Como podría corregir Este par de errores.

Creo que pasa porque estoy creando los options dentro del for, pero no se si ese es el problema ni como arreglarlo, gracias por la ayuda.

```
var car_info = [];

// Select de marcas 

brand_filter.addEventListener("change", function(){
    model_filter.innerHTML = "";
    var brand = brand_filter.value;
    if(brand){
        car_info[0] = brand;
        ajax_consult(car_info);
    }
});

//Select de modelos

model_filter.addEventListener("change", function(){
    var model = model_filter.value;
    if(model){
        car_info[1] = model;
        ajax_consult(car_info);
    }
});


model_filter.innerHTML = "";
const ajax_consult = (car_info) => {
    var brand = car_info[0];
    var model = car_info[1];
    $.get('/product/filters/'+ brand + "/" + model)
    .done(data =>{

        all_models = [];
        if(data.length > 0){
            for(i of data){
                /*==========================================
                Eliminando los modelos repetidos
                ===========================================*/
                all_models.push(i.model);
                var d = new Set(all_models);
                var result = [...d];
                console.log(result);

               //creando opciones para los modelos
                model_filter.removeAttribute("disabled");
                model_filter_option = document.createElement("option");
                model_filter_option.setAttribute("value", i.model);
                model_filter_option.innerHTML = i.model;
                model_filter.appendChild(model_filter_option);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Como lo mencioné el select modelos tiene dos elementos repetidos suburban 2020, hice clic en corvette y me lo duplicó, si hiciera clic en alguno de suburban 2020 mostraria 4. y los sigue ducplicando sin control al hacer clic

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el problema es que estás haciendo demasiadas cosas dentro del bucle. Además la clase Set no es capaz de ver si dos objetos son iguales, sólo funciona comprobando si son el mismo (lamentablemente a día de hoy no hay forma de definir un comparador para esta clase, como sí se puede hacer en Java o C#).

```
const ajax_consult = (car_info) => {
    var brand = car_info[0];
    var model = car_info[1];
    $.get('/product/filters/'+ brand + "/" + model)
    .done(data =>{
        
        const modelsAlreadyPresent = new Set();
        model_filter.removeAttribute("disabled");
        for(i of data){
          if (!modelsAlreadyPresent.has(i.model)) {
            //el set funciona con tipos primitivos, usemos string
            modelsAlreadyPresent.add(i.model);

            //creando opciones para los modelos
            const model_filter_option = document.createElement("option");
            model_filter_option.setAttribute("value", i.model);
            model_filter_option.innerHTML = i.model;
            model_filter.appendChild(model_filter_option);
          }
        }
    });
}
```